# Error 3020 if I try to navigate to a new record or save a record after a cancelled delete macro

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have a form that has two buttons.  One for save and new the other delete.  I used the macor wizard to create both of these.  Everything works fine if I use the delete and press Yes but if I press No to cancel the delete and then try to navigate to a new record or save the existing one I get  the error message "You tried to call Update or CancelUpdate or attempted to update a Field in a recordset without first calling AddNew or Edit. (Error 3020)".  Once I get this error the form hangs.  I can not do anything else on the form.  When I try to close the form I get the same message and it refuses to save the record before closing.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  There was a sub that ran when the form tried to delete that bombed.  What I did was in the form's before del confirm I ran a sub that set a global variable to true that I used in the sub that was causing the problem to exit early.  In the form's after del confirm I used a sub to reset the global variable to false.  Works great now.